# Binding IActiveViewEvents::ItemReordered to method in my ATL class?

Tags: arcobjects

How I can wire this event to my method?

I have an ATL class and I need to know when a layer added to map object so that I can update my list of layers in this class.My class implements IExtension and I've put this code in Startup method of this interface:

//Some code to obtain a reference to Map object
__hook(&IActiveViewEvents::ItemReordered,pMap/*pointer to map*/,&MyClass::MyEventHandler);

and in Shutdown method of IExtension I unhook it,but I receive compile error says the source and handler method not compatible while both signatures,arguments and names are exactly same.

Is it true a all this method?any simpler method for this wiring?or any reference on net?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution worked for me:

### 1.I added Interface IActiveViewEvents to my class so it seems like this

```
[
    coclass,

    default(IMyCOMClass),
    threading(apartment),
    vi_progid("myprg.MyCOMClass"),
    progid("myprg.MyCOMClass.1"),
    version(1.0),
    uuid("38A4302C-3513-4B20-9A38-318FE738FDCD"),
    helpstring("MyCOMClass Class"),

    implements_category(__uuidof(CATID_MxExtension))
]
class ATL_NO_VTABLE CMyCOMClass :
    public IMyCOMClass,
    public IExtension,
    public IActiveViewEvents
```

---

1. In Startup method of IExtension,this class is added to Map event
   listeners for IActiveViewEvents connection point by this code

   STDMETHOD(Startup)(VARIANT * initializationData)

   ```
   {
       if(initializationData==NULL)
           return E_POINTER;
       HRESULT hr;
       IDispatch* ipDsp;
       ipDsp=initializationData->pdispVal;
       if(FAILED(hr=ipDsp->QueryInterface(IID_IApplication,(void**)&this->m_ipApp)))
           return E_UNEXPECTED;
       IDocumentPtr ipDoc;
       //m_ipApp is member variable,keeps a pointer to ArcMap application,its type is IApplicationPtr
       if(FAILED(hr=this->m_ipApp->get_Document(&ipDoc)))
           return E_UNEXPECTED;
       //m_ipMxDoc is member variable of type IMxDocumentPtr
       this->m_ipMxDoc=(IMxDocumentPtr)ipDoc;
       IMapPtr ipMap;
       if(FAILED(hr=this->m_ipMxDoc->get_FocusMap(&ipMap)))
           return E_UNEXPECTED;
       //Hook to IActiveViewEvents connection point in Map COM Object
       //m_pComSource is member variable of type LPUNKNOWN,keeps pointer to event source
       LPUNKNOWN pComSink;
       if(FAILED(hr=ipMap->QueryInterface(IID_IUnknown,(LPVOID*)&this->m_pComSource)))
           return hr;
       if(FAILED(hr=this->QueryInterface(IID_IUnknown,(LPVOID*)&pComSink)))
           return hr;
       //m_Cookie is member variable of type DWORD,will be used when we want to disconnect this class from event source
       if(FAILED(hr=AtlAdvise(this->m_pComSource,pComSink,IID_IActiveViewEvents,&this->m_Cookie)))
       {
           this->m_Cookie=0;
           return hr;
       }
       return S_OK;
   }
   ```

---

3.Finally,the tie beetwen this class and Map object(as event source) will be removed when this class shutdowns

```
STDMETHOD(Shutdown)()

    {
        if(this->m_Cookie!=0)
        {
            AtlUnadvise(this->m_pComSource,IID_IActiveViewEvents,this->m_Cookie);
        }
        return  S_OK;
    }
```

---

now,my class listens to Map object to find when Map fires event methods like ItemAdded,ItemDeleted or ItemReordered.

Regards

Comment: What happens if you delete the dataframe (map) and add a new one, do you re-wire events to the newly added map?